# How to restore SQL Server backup to earlier time than latest available?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to restore a SQL Server `.bak` file to any time earlier than the time of last backup taken?

I can successfully restore a `.bak` file to the last backup taken. That looks like this. The backup set automatically appears.

[image: restore to last backup taken]

However, I want to restore to a point in time *before* the latest available (to a time before an accidental deletion of some item in that database). So I select Timeline and set as follows. The inverted triangle is the only one in the entire timeline.

[image]

But then, I can't restore, I get an error

> No backupset selected to be restored

[image]

I'm running SSMS as Administrator, using SQL Server 2017 Developer edition here. The original database was on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: `bak` files don't provide point in time restores, they provide a single restore point; the state the database was when the backup completed. It's the transaction logs that provide the point in time functionaility. If you need to restore to a point prior to the current `bak` file you have, you need to prior `bak` file and the relevant subsequent `trn` files.

Comment: If you have your database recovery mode set as SIMPLE, then such restore is not possible.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: @marc_s I did consider that, but google "no backup set selected to be restored" and behold the first 5 hits linking to SO, not to dba.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I thought as much, good to know I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Below the response from documentation:

> A specified time is always restored from a log backup. In every
> RESTORE LOG statement of the restore sequence, you must specify your
> target time or transaction in an identical STOPAT clause. As a
> prerequisite to a point-in-time restore, you must first restore a full
> database backup whose end point is earlier than your target restore
> time. That full database backup can be older than the most recent full
> database backup as long as you then restore every subsequent log
> backup, up to and including the log backup that contains your target
> point in time.

For more details look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Any news about it?